# Generate groups for multiple match rounds while minimizing the number of times two participants are in the same match

Tags: optimization, combinatorial-designs

We are hosting an event with 100 participants.
$20$ Participants can participate in one Match.
$5$ Matches with $20$ Participants each will be called one Round. (Each participant is only playing one Match per Round)
We are going to play $6$ Rounds.

We would like to minimize the number of times a participant is in the same match with another participant. (To be exact we would like to minimize the quadratic count, since it is better to have two participants seeing someone twice, than zero and four times.)

I am looking for any help, ether solutions or just keywords what a problem like this is called.

I tried the brute force approach with a small program, but it seems to converge rather quickly.

Comment: I agree that you have to consider the limitations of the cpu and memory in a typical home pc.  For example, when I sanity check Combinatorics problems by looping through all possible situations, I find that my pc handles $(10)^7$ iterations okay, but balks in the neighborhood of $(10)^8$ iterations.  If I was attacking your problem, I would consider the *smaller* problem of $(4)$ participants, rather than $(20)$, and $(20)$ total particpants rather than $(100)$.  I would then look for a pattern in the optimal solution found by the computer, and try to generalize a solution from that.

Comment: Very good idea!

Comment: *social golfer problem*

Comment: Charge the participants a fee, and use it to hire a mathematical consultant.

Answer (score 1):

This might or might not be the literal minimum, but it gives a result that's significantly better than random teams. We give the participants numbers between $1$ and $100$ that change from round to round, and in each round the matches are comprised of participants $1,\dots,20$, participants $21,\dots,40$, participants $41,\dots,60$, participants $61,\dots,80$, and participants $81,\dots,100$.

- Round one: Number the participants $1,2,\dots,100$.
- Round two:
  Multiply each participant's number by $18$ and reduce it modulo $101$
  (that is, replace each number by its remainder when divided by
  $101$).
- Round three: Again multiply each participant's number by $18$ and
  reduce it modulo $101$.
- Round four: Same thing.
- Round five: Same thing.
- Round six: Same thing.

With this scheme, $1{,}116$ pairs of participants are never in a match together, $2{,}369$ pairs of participants are in exactly one match together, $1{,}107$ are in exactly two matches together, $317$ are in three matches together, $39$ are in four matches together, and $2$ are in five matches together. The quadratic count, summed over all $4{,}950$ possible pairs of participants, is $10{,}324$.

(Random matches tends to yield quadratic counts around $11{,}000$ to $11{,}300$. By way of comparison, the best possible outcome would be if $4{,}200$ pairs of participants were in exactly one match together and $750$ pairs of participants were in exactly two matches together, giving a quadratic count of $7{,}200$.)

Comment: I think these numbers are now corrected.

Comment: Maybe ... want to reconstruct the configuration from scratch to verify it all?

Comment: I confirmed that your proposal yields 10324.  The correct counts are 1116, 2369, 1107, 317, 39, 2, 0.  I have also found a slight improvement to 10320.

Comment: Further improvements are in progress.  Down to 10250 so far.

Comment: go get 'em!  :-D

Comment: Thank you both! I am amazed, but the small amount of time you needed to code that. Did you script or program it? I can confirm your number for random draws.

Answer (score 1):

No proof of optimality, but here's a solution I obtained via integer linear programming.

```
Round 1
Match 1 {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}
Match 2 {21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40}
Match 3 {41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60}
Match 4 {61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80}
Match 5 {81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100}

Round 2
Match 1 {1,5,8,14,22,29,32,39,45,47,54,57,61,63,68,79,84,86,97,98}
Match 2 {9,10,11,17,25,26,33,38,44,50,56,60,67,71,72,80,87,88,91,93}
Match 3 {12,13,18,20,21,27,28,34,41,42,46,52,64,65,69,78,81,83,85,96}
Match 4 {2,4,7,15,23,35,36,40,49,53,55,58,66,70,74,76,82,90,99,100}
Match 5 {3,6,16,19,24,30,31,37,43,48,51,59,62,73,75,77,89,92,94,95}

Round 3
Match 1 {4,11,13,14,24,27,32,35,45,49,52,59,64,67,68,72,82,91,92,95}
Match 2 {6,7,16,17,21,22,34,50,54,55,60,65,70,73,78,79,87,89,98,99}
Match 3 {2,5,12,20,25,26,29,31,36,41,44,46,53,74,75,77,84,88,94,97}
Match 4 {1,8,10,18,23,28,37,38,43,47,51,56,62,63,66,80,81,85,90,100}
Match 5 {3,9,15,19,30,33,39,40,42,48,57,58,61,69,71,76,83,86,93,96}

Round 4
Match 1 {2,7,11,15,28,31,32,38,42,48,50,57,64,66,68,79,85,88,89,94}
Match 2 {4,6,17,18,25,33,39,41,51,52,60,61,63,70,74,84,92,95,96,100}
Match 3 {3,5,12,19,23,29,35,37,46,49,54,55,65,72,73,80,81,86,91,93}
Match 4 {1,10,13,14,21,22,27,30,36,44,45,56,58,62,75,76,77,83,87,99}
Match 5 {8,9,16,20,24,26,34,40,43,47,53,59,67,69,71,78,82,90,97,98}

Round 5
Match 1 {5,9,16,20,23,33,36,38,45,46,56,59,65,68,76,79,89,95,96,100}
Match 2 {1,13,17,19,28,29,30,31,41,47,50,53,64,70,71,80,82,86,92,99}
Match 3 {4,7,8,18,26,27,34,35,43,48,54,57,63,72,74,75,83,87,93,94}
Match 4 {10,11,12,15,21,24,25,32,42,51,55,58,61,62,73,78,84,90,91,97}
Match 5 {2,3,6,14,22,37,39,40,44,49,52,60,66,67,69,77,81,85,88,98}

Round 6
Match 1 {6,11,14,16,21,26,31,39,46,53,54,58,63,64,76,80,85,90,93,95}
Match 2 {4,7,17,19,24,29,34,36,44,51,56,59,61,66,68,78,81,83,86,88}
Match 3 {1,2,9,12,22,27,32,38,41,43,48,49,70,71,73,75,91,96,98,100}
Match 4 {3,5,13,18,23,25,28,40,45,50,55,57,62,67,69,74,87,89,92,97}
Match 5 {8,10,15,20,30,33,35,37,42,47,52,60,65,72,77,79,82,84,94,99}
```

It has quadratic count
$$1144 \cdot 0^2 + 2244 \cdot 1^2 + 1258 \cdot 2^2 + 276 \cdot 3^2 + 28 \cdot 4^2 + 0 \cdot 5^2 + 0 \cdot 6^2 = 10208.$$

Comment: Amazing result. I never got lower than 10600. I used a random solution to start with and then tried to find a better round to replace the worst round in the set.

Comment: Another idea for local improvement is to focus on two matches in the same round.